# tinytex in r: Font fplmri at 600 not found after tex live 2019 update, how to fix it?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tex-live, tinytex

I am using R markdown with tinytex to write my thesis. Some of the templates I'm using has used the `mathpazo` package.  After the Tex Live 2019 update, the tinytex on my computer couldn't use `mathpazo`: it looks for `"/fplmri[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)"`, then installs `mathpazo`, finds out `mathpazo` is already installed, looks for `"/fplmri[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)"` again, and can't find it, then stops.
This problem arises whenever the mathpazo package is used and math symbols are written.

I tried to compare the local mathpazo with the index online, the local copy seems complete to me. I tried to remove mathpazo and reinstall it using tinytex. That did not work either. I tried to use `lualatex` and `xelatex` instead of `pdfTeX`. They did not help/

This is the minimum sample I've written. There's basically nothing except I added mathpazo and wrote a math symbol...

(I have one backtick omitted in the sample below because StackOverflow uses backticks to decide which lines are in the code chunk. I don't know how to keep the backtick for the setup chunk and it still looks good)

````
---
title: "mini sample"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mathpazo}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
``

$\epsilon$
````

The errors messages are as follow

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
name = fplmri, rootname = fplmri, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find font fplmri in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf fplmri.mf

The command name is C:\Users\yangy\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find fplmri.mf .
I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf.
ps2pk cannot be used.
I try gsftopk.
gsftopk.exe fplmri 600
gsftopk cannot be used.
Next I try ttf2pk.
ttf2pk.exe -q fplmri 600
ttf2pk failed.
Finally I try hbf2gf.
hbf2gf.exe -q -p fplmri 600
All trials failed.

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 fplmri

The command name is C:\Users\yangy\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexpk
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
tlmgr search --file --global "/fplmri[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)"
Trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...
tlmgr install mathpazo
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: mathpazo
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
name = fplmri, rootname = fplmri, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find font fplmri in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf fplmri.mf

The command name is C:\Users\yangy\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexmf
Cannot find fplmri.mf .
I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf.
ps2pk cannot be used.
I try gsftopk.
gsftopk.exe fplmri 600
gsftopk cannot be used.
Next I try ttf2pk.
ttf2pk.exe -q fplmri 600
ttf2pk failed.
Finally I try hbf2gf.
hbf2gf.exe -q -p fplmri 600
All trials failed.

kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 fplmri

The command name is C:\Users\yangy\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexpk
kpathse
```

The last few lines in the log file shows

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file fplmri): Font fplmri at 600 not found
```

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to install fonts manually? Errors like this occur, when an incomplete `pdftex.map` file is found in a personal TEXMF tree. Have a look at the log-file from a (successful) pdftex run. It should contain a line like `{<some/path>pdftex.map}` near the end. What's the `<some/path>`?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar issue I was able to fix with:

```
install.packages("knitr")
install.packages("rticles")
install.packages("tinytex")
tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()
```